# How to add .less css files in custom theme magento 2

Tags: less, custom-theme, paths, magento2.4.4, steps

I want to add **the custom.less file in my custom theme** which i want to develop from scratch.

so, anyone have an idea then please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let’s assume that you have created custom theme. Now, Create your custom less file and add your less code inside that file.

   app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/web/css/source/_custom.less
2. After that you need to import this _custom.less file

   app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/web/css/source/_sources.less

**@import '_custom.less';**

You need to import your _custom.less file using this above line. Just add that line inside _sources.less file. If this _sources.less file not exist in your custom theme then, you need to copy file from
**vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_sources.less** file in your theme.

Now, just need to deploy and clean cache.

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: Thank you for response.